# How to give more resources to Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp, mac-osx

I downloaded the Ethereum Wallet a few weeks ago. Since then it has been syncing with the network (I don't have it running all the time). As today  the block download progress is 3.700.000/3.912.000.

I been researching how to make the process faster and the general answer is that the process is slow because is very cpu intensive, which brings up my question.

While the app is running in my computer the cpu usage doesn't reach 15%, the network usage is less than 1mbps (of 300 available) and the disk read and write speeds are around 10MB/s.

[image]

**So I do not understand what is being the bottleneck**. Maybe the program itself has a limit assigned in the use of resources.

So I was wondering if that is the case and **how I could make Ethereum Wallet take advantage of my computer resources to achieve a faster syncing.**

UPDATE

I'm running Geth 1.6.5

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a hard disk drive instead a solid state drive?

Answer (score 1):

When loading the blockchain, the system verifies each and every part of a transaction, looking back into the blockchain, if the data was correctly linked. The process read's and writes data (on my spinning harddisk with an average of 5-7MBytes/sec). This makes the hard disk get used heavily, and the whole process slow. If it is a spinning harddisk, then this is probably the root cause, because the I/O cycles eat up all the time, and the CPU remains "fairly" idle. You didn't mention which wallet you are using... In Geth (go-ethereum) you can assign more memory to the app:
geth --cache 2048 console
This will speed up the process, cause disk I/O cycles are avoided.
Alternativly an SSD would be a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Geth 1.6.5, I will update the question to mention it. Is there a way of running the command in the app (I don't find it) or I have to run the wallet from the terminal?

Comment: I am running only unixoide environments, can't help on Windows. I have only seen the command line parameter "--cache"...